# NodeJs - One async function forced me to make all my functions async

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, knex.js

I'm working on a web application using expressjs and knexjs packages.
because knex functions are async or promise-based, I have to make all my functions async too.
for example if I have 3 functions:

```
async function accessDb() {
   return await knex.some_query();
}

async function doSomething() {
  let db_result = await accessDb();
  // do something with db_result;
  return some_result;
}

async function doMore() {
    let something_result = await doSomething();
    //....
    return true;
}
```

How can I stop making all my functions async because of one async function?

Answer (score -1):

It names is Promise hell/ async&await hell,

You can use `Promise.all` function, like:

```js
Promise.all([
   doSomething(),
   doMore()
]).then(() => doMoreThanMore())
```

another solution is:

```js
function doMore() {
    doSomething()
       .then((something_result) => {
           doMoreMore()
       })
    //....
    return true;
}
```